# socat openssl-listen - ensuring TLSv1.3 is in use

Tags: openssl, socat, tls1.3

I have a working client/server scenario using `socat` with the following commands:

**Server**

```
socat openssl-listen:5000,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=server.crt,verify=0 STDIO
```

**Client**

```
socat stdio openssl-connect:localhost:5000,cert=server.pem,cafile=server.crt,verify=0
```

This is part of a larger system, but the commands above work well for what we are trying to achieve. However, I need to ensure that TLS v1.3 is in use, and ensure it is the only version of encryption being used. I can ensure version 1.2 is used using something like:

`socat - OPENSSL-LISTEN:443,method=TLS1.2,verify=0,cert=cert.pem,key=key.pem`

openssl is at the latest (1.1.1 version), which is supposed to support TLS1.3

At time of writing (Feb 2020), almost all the documentation I can find for socat only makes reference to setting TLS1.2, and no reference to TLS1.3. For the `openssl` command line, you can set `-tls1_3`, for instance:

`openssl s_server -accept 443  -tls1_3 -ciphersuites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 -key key.pem -cert cert.pem`

[1] https://8gwifi.org/docs/tlsv13.jsp

This command works (alongside the relevant `s_client` command), but I cannot get the same parameters passed in through socat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socat` version 1.7.4.0 and later supports the option `openssl-min-proto-version`[1] for which a valid value is `TLS1.3`. This will enforce that TLS v1.3 or later is used.

Your commands would thus become:

#### Server

```
socat openssl-listen:5000,reuseaddr,cert=server.pem,cafile=server.crt,verify=0,openssl-min-proto-version=TLS1.3 STDIO
```

#### Client

```
socat stdio openssl-connect:localhost:5000,cert=server.pem,cafile=server.crt,verify=0,openssl-min-proto-version=TLS1.3
```

Note that this does not enforce that *exactly* TLS v1.3 is used. To do that, append `,openssl-max-proto-version=TLS1.3` to the list of options (so that both *min* and *max* equals `TLS1.3`).

[1] https://fossies.org/linux/socat/CHANGES